# flex crossdomain doesn't work

Tags: flash, apache-flex, crossdomain.xml

I have two domains being hosted on the same server as different vhosts.  I'm using apache2 web server.

Both domains (domain1 and domain2) are using https.

I have the same flex app being loaded from domain1 and domain2, and it pulls data ONLY with requests to domain1.

When the app is loaded from domain1 and requests data from domain1, the app works fine.

When the app is loaded from domain2 and requests data from domain1, the app does not work.  I get the following error:

"Security error accessing url
Destination: DefaultHTTPS"

I do have a crossdomain file located at https://www.domain1/crossdomain.xml, and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="domain1" secure="false" />
    <allow-access-from domain="domain2" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

In my flex code, I have the following lines of code:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile( "https://www.domain1/crossdomain.xml" );
```

I cannot get it to work, and I've been stuck on this for too long.  How can I get it to work?

Comment: Do you have a crossdomain file in each vhost root?

Comment: Yes the crossdomain file is in the root directory for each vhost

Comment: Where is the "DefaultHTTPS" destination defined?  In a services config file or elsewhere?  Are you using self signed certificates for the HTTPS servers?

Comment: Its defined in a services config file.  I am not using self-signed certs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you remove the secure=false.